# Using Embarcadero Borland

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, c++builder

As I'm more and more dissapointed with VS 2010 I'm trying to find some alternative and I was looking at Embarcadero's new edition of C++ env.
Is there any point of learning new (not popular I think) product when VS practically dominates market?
Thanks.

Comment: I work for past 10 years with Linux and *NIX and never heard of the "VS" thing you speak of.

Comment: @Dummy never heard of Visual Studio? Wow!

Comment: ha: the "VS dominates market" was begging for it ;)

Comment: @Dummy What is this Linux thing you speak of? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using both the Embarcadero Borland, now RAD Studio 2010, c++ and VS2008 every day for the last 6 months. My programming philosophy has always been to use the right tool for the project, no matter what that particular tool is.   So a couple of my observations/opinions are -

Advantages

1. The WYSIWYG screen designer is good.  It acts a lot like the WinForms editor in VS2008, but for c++.   In VS2008, the only package for c++ that I've used that is close is Qt.   My biggest compliant is documentation, but that applies to most software, so it isn't just their problem.
2. For many builtin classes, they are built on TObject class.  This base class functions a lot like Object in C#.  The biggest advantage this gives you as a c++ programmer, if you follow a few rules, is mostly automatic memory management.   It's not garbage collection, rather, list of related objects that are deleted together.

Disadvantages-

1. The RAD Studio 2010 C++ environment exists primarily to support Delphi.  That is their real strength anyway.  Nowhere does anything say this.  It is just an overall feel that I've gotten from using system.
2. Limited support for 3rd party libraries.

   3. It cannot link with any Microsoft compatible c++ library.  This includes both Microsoft and 3rd party libraries. They use a different "name mangling" format from Microsoft.  So everything has to wrapped in a c language wrapper.
   4. We use the Boost Libraries a lot in VS2008.  But in Rad Studio, it only has limited support for Boost.
3. I've found the overall speed of the generated code to significantly slower than that produced by VS2008.

Please remember, that these are just one person's opinions.

I would suggest that you download a demo version of the product and try it for yourself.

Comment: Eeek! Limited support for Boost? Does that mean that the compiler isn't standards-compliant? Oh how the mighty have fallen!!

Comment: As I understand it, Yes.  Boost's problem is the complier doesn't correctly handle template expansions. The limited Boost support comes in the form of a customized version of Boost 1.39 with the complier.  Qt doesn't compile for the same reason.

Comment: "The biggest advantage [TObject] gives you as a c++ programmer, if you follow a few rules, is mostly automatic memory management." This is not true. There is *NO* automatic memory management in `TObject`-derived classes, at least in the desktop compilers (there is in the iOS compiler, via ARC). Maybe you are thinking of `TComponent`, which allows one `TComponent`-derived object to *own* another `TComponent`-derived object and free it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm not really a Windows programmer, I have been using Borland/Embarcadero to-and-fro during the past 10 years. Here are my personal opinions of why you should not consider it:

- The general quality of Builder has dropped significantly over the years. Borland Builder 6 was the last high-quality product, from there the IDE itself has become more and more buggy. The IDE typically crashes once per 1-2 weeks of usage.
- No undo in the RAD design. Yes I know, it is quite unbelievable. Even the earliest versions of utter crap like VB had this. But Builder year 2011 doesn't! If you slip on your keyboard and accidentally alter a component, you shall be punished!
- The debugger is next to useless. This might have been fixed in the latest version, but in several versions you can't single step through the program without collapsing struct/class variables in the watch window, which is of course very frustrating.
- Documentation is very poor, often non-existant, and may be written in Object Pascal, even though you ordered the C++ IDE. The help files also have a tendency to linger as evil ghost processes in your computer, making it impossible to shut down Windows before the ghost is busted.

Personally I'm considering switching to Visual Studio.

Comment: Sounds a lot like my experiences in other Borland products.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be 100% up-to-date, you have to use the development environment provided by the platform's vendor.

If you do not mind waiting few months/years for new things to get ported over (or your market allows for it) then you surely you can venture into the unknown.

It's not that Borland's IDEs (unlike MS' VS family) needed any advanced training to start using them and be already productive. That is the main reason why they remain popular in many niches.

Comment: so basicaly what you're saying there is little point in touching Borland?

Comment: If you are already experienced developer - no. Borland was always friendly to newcomers. Some types of applications (light GUI, DB/SQL/reports) were very very easy to develop and deploy. Rest was hit and miss. If one manage to find a ready component for the task, then it is a piece of cake. Otherwise - bag of hurt.

Comment: Or from another perspective, to understand the ground-laying concept of Borland's RADs: they initially was trying to appeal to and entice the VB users.

Comment: Been using Borland for over 10 years and continue with active development using Borland C++ Builder 5. Been very successful. No plans to port to a newer IDE anytime soon.

Comment: @Code Monkey Borland C++ Builder 5??!??!  That compiler was sooo buggy.  If you use it regularly then I am sure you can attest to the linker errors, out of memory, et cetera.

Comment: @Man: You seem a little young to be used to C++ Builder 5 (it came out in 2000). At any rate, that's one of the reasons I left that job in May of this year :) But the IDE was a beast.. like a Ford Pinto. Just bang the hood a couple times and it will get you back on the road.